# How does imports work with the @ in the references with javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-3.x

I am struggling to figure out how references work with for example :

```
import { PolymerElement } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
```

when I want to use third party web components I often find references like this.
And I could not get this to work unless I change the reference to

```
import { PolymerElement } from '../../@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
```

relative to where I placed polymer folder inside my project.
I understand I should not need to do this. and if I want to import more third party tools this would be tedious to change all the references.

So how does the reference actually supposed to work and how am I supposed to "Correctly" do the import and get this to work?
I searched up, maybe I am search with terrible key works or something, but I don't see anyone explaining this.

Can someone explain how this works and how am I actually supposed to get these references to work instead of changing all the path to relative path?

Thanks

Comment: I think people setup webpack `alias`es for this e.g. http://xabikos.com/2015/10/03/Webpack-aliases-and-relative-paths/#Webpack-Resolve-Alias-solution

Comment: checkout this link as well https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias

Comment: I'll take a look thanks.

Comment: I am not getting it this is just using another package to handle reference.
I am wondering let's say I have an existing project.
I want to add another module however I noticed from the github after I download the component the reference in the javascript file are all : 
import { PolymerElement } from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
How does npm handle the reference? when I add third party component how does the reference work here? I shouldn't need to change all the reference to match my own path. It should just work as they come in right?

Comment: how does the project expect to know '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js'; is pointing at? I am confused.

Comment: because by default webpack resolve imports from `node_modules` so if you do `import SOMETHING from 'somewhere'` it will look into `node_modules/somewhere`

Answer (score 0):

I found out why.
Seem like projects automatically look for directory called node_modules as long I put my folders under that it automatically find those references